# how to communicate an android activity with javascript code and vise versa in phonegap android?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am new to phonegap development. I want's to know how to communicate our phonegap webpage to native android activity and vise versa and give me any tutorial for phonegap learning.Please can any one help me.

Thanking in Advance.

Comment: If you want to develop native Android apps then this is a good place to start... http://developer.android.com/about/start.html

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that this is a Q&A site, where you post problematic code and errors and other users kindly point the issues in your code, not a "please teach me site". Please edit your post to show some research effort.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use cordova.exec API in able to communicate between javascript code and android activity. Maybe this link can help you.

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/06_05_Android_-_Adding_native_functionality_to_hybrid_application_with_Apache_Cordova_plugin.pdf

First thing you need to declare your custom plugin in config.xml

```
<feature name="CustomPlugin">
      <param name="android-package" value="com.AndroidApacheCordovaPlugin.CustomPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Implementing the plug-in by using Java code

```
public class CustomPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) 
            throws JSONException {

        if (action.equals("sayHello")){
            try {
                String responseText = "Hello world, " + args.getString(0);
                callbackContext.success(responseText);
            } catch (JSONException e){
                callbackContext.error("Failed to parse parameters");
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Calling a plug-in from JavaScript

```
function initial(){
    var name = $("#NameInput").val();
    cordova.exec(sayHelloSuccess, sayHelloFailure, "CustomPlugin", "sayHello", [name]);
}

function sayHelloSuccess(data){
    alert("OK: " + data);
}

function sayHelloFailure(data){
    alert("FAIL: " + data);
}
```

Comment: thank you  Dato' Mohammad Nurdin  the link what you shared given a clear understanding on plugins