# Cordova 3.4 has plugin translate language ?

Tags: cordova

I am new developer with cordova so i want to know that cordova 3.4 has a plugin of translate  language or not? Please tell me if someone know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you need to create a custom cordova plugin. You can try these 2.

**Solution 1**

Custom cordova plugin

iOS: [Phonegap jsCallback in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315632/phonegap-jscallback-in-objective-c/22316202#22316202)

android: [how to communicate an android activity with javascript code and vise versa in phonegap android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296117/how-to-communicate-an-android-activity-with-javascript-code-and-vise-versa-in-ph/22296475#22296475)

**Solution 2**

Using sessionStorage and web service. You need to set multiple language setting in your database. User can select their language when their trigger from client side, send request to the server and get the response in a set of language then inject into sessionStorage. Done.